# Can't install HTK on linux

Tags: linux, htk

I wan't to use ALIZE for speaker recognition and after the instalation there is one of the steps: *feature extraction using SPRO or HTK* So I downloaded zip file of HTK and using terminal I configured everything, but when entering **make all** I'm getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:56: recipe for target 'HSLab' failed
make[1]: *** [HSLab] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/username/Downloads/htk/HTKTools'
Makefile:108: recipe for target 'htktools' failed
make: *** [htktools] Error 1
```

what does it mean and how to fix this? I'm looking for answer for hours and can't find anything...

I'm using HTK 3.4.1 stable version and LInux ubuntu 16.10

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: @Aurora0001 I'm using HTK 3.4.1 stable version and LInux ubuntu 16.10

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this, [check out this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178508/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lx11-error-when-installing-htk/1084878#1084878)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error `cannot find -lX11` means that `ld` can't find the libraries for X11 (the X.Org display server). The required libraries can be found in the [`libx11-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libx11-dev) package which can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
```

This should resolve your issue, as long as the libraries install in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (which is likely if `apt-get` handles it).

On 64-bit systems, you might need to explicitly state the 32-bit version is required:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev:i386
```

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install libx11-dev:i386` work for you? Might be a 32/64 bit issue.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much! You can edit your answer and I'll mark it as correct answer.